# »Repository« oder »Repositorium«?

Tags: declension, anglicism

Ich schreibe eine Arbeit über ein zwei wöchiges Programmierprojekt, und zwar auf Deutsch.

Ein Problem bei der Dokumentation ist es, falsche Anglizismen zu vermeiden.

Welches ist die richtige Form: *Git-Repositories* oder *Git-Repositorien?*

Falls ihr mehr Informationen zu Git/Repositories braucht: Wikipedia zu [Repositories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repository_(revision_control)) und [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)). Das ist ein Tool zur Versionsverwaltung von Software/Dateien. Es wird sehr häufig im Jargon der Softwareentwicklung gebraucht, welcher viele englische Wörter enthält.

Comment: Willkommen auf German Language SE. Zurzeit ist Deine Frage hauptsächlich eine des Geschmacks und deswegen nicht gut geeignet für unsere Seite. Kannst Du Deine Frage so abändern, dass sie sachlicher ist? Zum Beispiel könntest Du fragen, ob eher *Repositiories* oder *Repositiorien* im Programmierkontext gängig sei oder anhand welcher Kriterien Du Dir Deine eigene Meinung bilden könnest

Comment: Oder was der korrekte Plural ist ;)

Comment: [Repositorium](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Repositorium), Plural Repositorien "EDV: Speicherplatz für Daten"

Comment: Ich habe nie den Sinn erkannt, die deutche Fachbegriffe zu verwenden, wenn in der Praxis keiner sie verwendet und es alles nur verschleiert. Bald redest du von Kellerspeicher oder der Nebenreihenfolgebaumtraversierung. Ich verstehe, dass es für eine Arbeit ist, aber es hat mich ehrlich überrascht wieviele Professoren der Informatik sich als Sprachpedanten entpuppt haben.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Duden behauptet, das eingedeutschte Wort für einen Datenspeicherort in der EDV sei [Repositorium](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Repositorium) (plur. Repositorien). Nun hört man das aber kaum in Zusammenhang mit Software-Paketquellen. Hier lese ich meist unverändert den englische Fachterminus **Repository** (plur. Repositories).

Das folgende [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Repository%2CRepositorium&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRepository%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRepositorium%3B%2Cc0) weist auch in diese Richtung ("Repositorium" wird hier wahrscheinlich meist in der Bedeutung eines (historischen) Aktenarchivs gefunden):

[image]

Eindeutig wird die Verwendung des englischen Ausdruck in der Kombination mit Git, denn dann handelt es sich um einen Eigennamen, den man gar nicht übersetzen soll. Ich empfehle also die Verwendung:

> **Git-Repository / Git-Repositories**

Wenn man unbedingt einen eingedeutschten Begriff verwenden muss, ist "Git-Repositorium / Git - Repositorien" nicht falsch, aber vielleicht weniger verständlich.

Comment: Merci  great way to find out what to use.

Comment: @YannikAmmann: ja, aber man muss bei den Ngrams aufpassen, die können täuschen. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) evtl. auch mit verlinkten deutschsprachigen Artikeln hilf auch sehr oft.

Comment: Das hatte ich mir auch gedacht jedoch gibt es für repositories keine deutsche Seite. Jedoch bin ich nicht auf die Idee gekommen auf der deutschen Git Seite zu schauen was verwendet wird. 

Answer (score 1):

In der Programmierwelt werden halt häufig englische Ausdrücke der Einfachheit halber benutzt. Wenn *Git-Repositories* effektiv im Code vorkommt oder in der Branche gängig ist, würde ich das benutzen. Wenn du es eindeutschen möchtest, dann kannst du auch *Git-Ablagen* benutzen. Es klingt aber irgendwie komisch in meinen Ohren. *Git-Repositorien* ist die schlechteste Option; hier hast du einfach ein Fremdwort für *Ablage.*

Comment: Kurz: Du weißt nicht, was ein Repository ist.

Comment: Doch doch, ich weiss es schon.

Comment: Sorry, mein Irrtum.

Comment: Schon gut. Mein Wissen in Informatik war trotzdem nicht genügend, um die Frage fachgerecht zu beantworten. Aber man lernt ja immer dazu :)

Comment: In der deutschsprachigen IT-Branche spricht man **ausschließlich** von *Git-Repositories* bzw. von einem *Git-Repository* (falls im Singular). Lass Dich von anderslautenden Kommentaren nicht verunsichern.